# Why does Apostol introduce the $\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt=F(b)-F(a)$ property at this point (before discussing differentiation)? Motivations?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

So far I have only learnt about what definite integrals are, how to compute them, some applications, etc. Now, Apostol has introduced the concept of indefinite integrals (Calculus Vol. 1, pg. 120).

He defines an indefinite integral of some function $f$ as a new function $F$ such that
$$F(x)=\int_{n}^{x}f(t)dt,$$
where $n$ is a constant and $x$ is a variable.

He then goes on to describe some properties of indefinite integrals. One property states that for any definite integral of $f$ with lower and upper bounds $a$ & $b$ respectively, the definite integral of $f$ can be computed by evaluating an indefinite integral of $f$ at $a$ & $b$ and taking the difference, i.e,
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt=F(b)-F(a)$$
I understand that this property is true, however **what I don't understand is what the purpose of this property is**.

Essentially, he says that if we want to evaluate some definite integral of $f$ with bounds $a$ & $b$, what we can do instead is evaluate two different definite integrals of $f$, namely $\int_{n}^{b}f(t)dt$ & $\int_{n}^{a}f(t)dt$, and take their difference.

But why would we ever want to do this? This doesn't seem like a very useful technique for computing definite integrals, unless we knew the equation for $F$ from the start.

I understand that this property becomes very important and useful down the line once derivatives are introduced, but shouldn't this property be introduced then, after learning about derivatives? Why am I learning about it here? In this context, it feels very unmotivated.

So then why did Apostol decide to introduce this property now rather than later?

EDIT: What I am told in the comments of this post (I think) is that all I must know at this point is that the property is true; that there exists some function $F$ such that finding the equation for $F$ essentially means we're able to turn any "evaluate this definite integral of $f$" problem into a basic subtraction problem. Right now we have no technique for finding the equation for $F$, but down the line we will (once we learn about antidifferentiation).

So, at this point, our only job as the reader is to understand that such a function exists, understand how it is that this property is true (by going through the proof), and move on. That's all.

Is this correct?

Comment: The point is that, once you know one indefinite integral $F$, then you can compute integral of $f$ on any interval by evaluating $F$. If you don't have it, you have to compute integral over each interval at each time again.

Comment: This does seem quite useful if you know $F$, but so far I know of no technique for finding $F$ (apart from taking definite integrals). Thus the property seems a bit useless at this point, as if you just create more work for yourself by using it.

Comment: There is no preliminary discussion about this idea as far as I can see

Comment: What he is saying that there is some function F which allows you to compute integrals. There is nothing more to it, and he is not saying that this will rock your world, that finding the function is easy, or anything. Simply that given f you can (in principle) find a function that lets you compute integrals.

Comment: There is a tendency nowadays in students to endlessly trudge in finessing things… Very unconducive to anything useful tendency.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I see. So all he really wants from the reader at this point is to understand that this property is true, and move on? I'm just overthinking it massively?

Comment: You are presumably learning calculus, not how to organize calculus textbooks!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Yes, I just thought that if I didn't understand what the purpose of the property is, I didn't understand it well enough, maybe that I was missing something. But I guess I should've just taken it at face value. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Once definite integrals have been taught, the existence of primitives (a.k.a. [antiderivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative)) is a direct consequence of the (very intuitive) additive property of areas.  It would be even less justifiable to *not* formalize the notion at that point. It's not done for the practical purpose of actually *evaluating* any definite integral, but for the pedagogical purpose of conveying and consolidating the meaning of definite integrals.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "the pedagogical purpose of conveying and consolidating the meaning of definite integrals"? I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: Also, my issue isn't really in understanding why indefinite integrals should be introduced, I just don't understand the "point" of $\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt=F(b)-F(a)$. It feels unmotivated. I don't really see what this property is useful for.. do you mean that introducing this property now is pedagogically useful as a kind of primer for when I *do* learn about differentiation and eventually about the second FTC?

Comment: @MahdiRkioui If you "glue" two rectangles together, their combined area is the sum of the two areas of each individual rectangle. That's what I meant by "*the (very intuitive) additive property of areas*". Now, once the definite integral has been defined, it holds true that $\int_n^a f + \int_a^b f = \int_n^b f$, as you wrote into the question. At that point, a student may begin to realize that, or wonder whether/how, that's equivalent to the additivity of areas. Formalizing it as $\int_a^b f = F(b) - F(a)$ is meant to reinforce that intuition.

Comment: Again, it's not about how you will be later able to use it to calculate definite integrals. It's about solidifying the correct intuition of definite integrals to begin with.

Comment: So, this idea has nothing to do with finding an easier way to compute definite integrals, and is just some kind of pedagogical tool for reinforcing the intuition for the additive property of areas? Doesn't the additive property imply this property? Not the other way around? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @MahdiRkioui Yes, it's not a practical tool to calculate definite integrals at that point (except maybe in simple made-up cases). Also, yes, it's just a way to formalize the additivity of areas. That's a very intuitive notion, from back in preschool years even, but it was most likely never formalized or proved before.

Comment: Doesn't the additive property itself imply this property? I don't quite understand how it is that the $F(b)-F(a)$ property implies the additive property.. shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: In fact, I think Apostol takes the additive property as an axiom, and then derives properties from it (properties like $F(b)-F(a)=\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt$).

Comment: @MahdiRkioui That depends on how *you* formally define "area" and "additive property" before/without definite integrals.

Comment: On pg. 57 of Apostol: "Our approach to this problem is to start with a number of properties we feel area should have and take these as axioms for area. Any set function which satisfies these axioms will be called an area function. To make certain we are not discussing an empty theory, it is necessary to show that an area function actually exists. We shall not attempt to do this here. Instead, we assume the existence of an area function and deduce further properties from the axioms."

Comment: One of these axioms is the additive property you mention.

Comment: My point is that I don't understand why the additive axiom is used to derive this property.. what exactly is the point of this property? Why bring it up now if it isn't useful for computing definite integrals (this is pretty much all I've done so far in the book)?

Comment: @MahdiRkioui I don't see how any of that goes against what I wrote before. But, anyway, all I had to say is in my answer as posted. I thought that was pertinent to the question and perhaps even useful, but maybe I misunderstood what you were really asking, In that case, sorry, but I don't really have anything more to add.

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In section 1.23, Apostol computes directly from his definition of the integral that $$\int_0^b x^p\,dx = \frac{b^{p+1}}{p+1}.$$

Putting a zero as the lower bound just makes the notation in the proof a bit less cumbersome.

Applying the property you mention, we conclude that $$\int_a^b x^p\, dx = \frac{b^{p+1}}{p+1} - \frac{a^{p+1}}{p+1}.$$

You're right to notice that working on $[0, b]$ is not fundamentally different from working on $[a, b]$ (that's what your theorem is saying in fact!). It's just that sometimes starting the interval at a nice number like $0$ or $1$, depending on the situation, can make the notation nicer, and we don't lose anything from it.

Answer (score 0):

One reason to treat integration first is that it applies to all functions that the learner is familiar with—in particular step functions and the modulus function. Differentiation is more awkward. Often, the beginner, on introduction to calculus via differentiation, will assume that any function that can described can be differentiated, perhaps except for certain points. In fact, it was only well into the 19th century that nowhere-differentiable functions were discovered. From the modern perspective of what functions are, it seems natural to describe a reciprocal pair of operations (more correctly, a single operation corresponding to a family of operations reciprocal to it) by introducing the more generally applicable one first.

Comment: My question is about what the purpose of $\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt=F(b)-F(a)$ is, not why integration is taught before differentiation, sorry if I didn't make that clear in the question.

Comment: @MahdiRkioui : I answered what I took to be the question in the title. Perhaps you should consider editing it.